# object attribute issue using classes

Tags: python

I am defining 2 classes and using the first one as the input for the second one, but I get an "object has no attribute" error when I execute it. Here is a short version of my code, I tried to reduce the size by using ...; All the variables that are being fed into he functions and classes are defined in the body of the code.

```
# %% imports
...

@dataclass
class newBasicImage:
    """
    Args:
        local_path (Path): Local path of the file
        meta (dict): meta data associated with the image
        mask (ndarray): mask data associated with the image
        height_data (ndarray): height data associated with the image
    """
    local_path: Path = None
    meta: dict = None
    mask: np.ndarray = None
    height_data: np.ndarray = None

@dataclass
class LPXLSrc():
    def create_height_image_from_SDF_height(self, basic_image: newBasicImage) -> BasicHeightImage:
            """
            Args:
                basic_image: newBasicImage

            """

            local_path = basic_image.local_path
            ...
            basic_himage = BasicHeightImage(
                local_path = local_path,
                meta=basic_image.meta,
                height_data=vr_height,
                z_units=units,
                mm_per_pixel=basic_image.meta["x_mmperpixel"],
                mask=img_mask,
                optical_image=vr_optical,
            )
            return basic_himage
...
mm_per_pxl = y_scale*1000
meta = {
     'x_mmperpixel': mm_per_pxl, 
     'y_mmperpixel': mm_per_pxl, 
     'XYCalibration': mm_per_pxl*1E-03, 
     'Unit': 'Micrometer', 
     'Digits': 6, 
     'camera_serial_number': '#AC910123'}

SDF_basic_image = {
    'local_path' : {},
    'meta' : meta,
    'mask' : ns,
    'height_data' : ns,
}

height_image = LPXLSrc().create_height_image_from_SDF_height(SDF_basic_image)
...
```

When I run this, this is the error message:

```
--> 265 height_image = LPXLSrc().create_height_image_from_SDF_height(SDF_basic_image)
...
...
...
---> 61         local_path = basic_image.local_path
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'local_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `SDF_basic_image` is a dictionary:

```py
SDF_basic_image = {
    'local_path' : {},
    'meta' : meta,
    'mask' : ns,
    'height_data' : ns,
}
```

To access it's `local_path` member, you need to use this form:

```py
        local_path = basic_image["local_path"]
```

The other form

```py
        local_path = basic_image.local_path
```

you can use if you make your `SDF_basic_image` a class / object:

```py
class SDF_basic_image:
    local_path = {}
    meta = meta
    mask = ns
    height_data = ns
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this worked but I am not sure if this was the right place to define the class:  `mm_per_pxl = y_scale*1000
        meta = {
            'x_mmperpixel': mm_per_pxl, 
            'y_mmperpixel': mm_per_pxl, 
            'XYCalibration': mm_per_pxl*1E-03, 
            'Unit': 'Micrometer', 
            'Digits': 6, 
            'camera_serial_number': '#AC910123'}

        class SDF_basic_image:
            local_path = {}
            meta = meta
            mask = ns
            height_data = ns`